# How to create 2 different running app with the same docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, devops

I already have a docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
version: "3.1"

services:

memcached:
  image: memcached:alpine
  container_name: dl-memcached

redis:
  image: redis:alpine
  container_name: dl-redis

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7.21
  container_name: dl-mysql
  restart: unless-stopped
  working_dir: /application
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=dldl
    - MYSQL_USER=docker
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
  volumes:
    - ./../:/application
  ports:
    - "8007:3306"

phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  container_name: dl-phpmyadmin
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - PMA_HOST=dl-mysql
    - PMA_PORT=3306
    - MYSQL_USER=docker
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8002:80
  volumes:
    - /application
  links:
    - mysql

elasticsearch:
  build: phpdocker/elasticsearch
  container_name: dl-es
  volumes:
    - ./phpdocker/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
  ports:
    - "8003:9200"

webserver:
  image: nginx:alpine
  container_name: dl-webserver
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
      - ./../:/application:delegated
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx:delegated
  ports:
   - "9003:80"

php-fpm:
  build: phpdocker/php-fpm
  container_name: dl-php-fpm
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - ./../:/application:delegated
    - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    - ./../docker/php-fpm/certs/store_stock/:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
    - ./logs:/var/log:delegated # nginx logs
    - /application/var/cache 
  environment:
    XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
    PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=dl"

node:
  build:
    dockerfile: dl/phpdocker/node/Dockerfile
    context: ./../
  container_name: dl-node
  working_dir: /application
  ports:
    - "8008:3000"
  volumes:
    - ./../:/application:cached
  tty: true
```

My goal is to have 2 isolate environments working at the same time in the same server with the same docker-compose file? I wonder if it's possible?

I want to be able to stop and update one env. while the other one is still running and getting the traffic.

Maybe I need another approach in my case?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with what you're trying to do. If your goal is to put things behind a load balancer, I think that rather than trying to start multiple instances of your project, a better solution would be to use the scaling features available to docker-compose. In particular, if your goal is to put some services behind a load balancer, you probably don't want multiple instances of things like your database.

If you combine this with a dynamic front-end proxy like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), you can make the configuration largely automatic.

Consider a very simple example consisting of a backend container running a simple webserver and a traefik frontend:

```
---
version: "3"

services:

  webserver:
    build:
      context: web
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.port: 80
      traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefix:/"

  frontend:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api
      - --docker
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
```

If I start it like this, I get a single backend and a single frontend:

```
docker-compose up
```

But I can also ask `docker-compose` to scale out the backend:

```
docker-compose up --scale webserver=3
```

In this case, I get a single frontend and **three** backend servers. Traefik will automatically discover the backends and will round-robin connections between them. You can download [this example](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-55533491) and try it out.

### Caveats

There are a few aspects of your configuration that would need to change in order to make this work (and in fact, you would need to change them even if you were to create multiple instances of your project as you have proposed in your question).

#### Conflicting paths

Take for example the configuration of your `webserver` container:

```
volumes:
    - ./logs:/var/log/nginx:delegated
```

If you start two instances of this service, both containers will mount `./logs` on `/var/log/nginx`. If they both attempt to write to `/var/log/nginx/access.log`, you're going to have problems.

The easiest solution here is to avoid bind mounts for things like log directories (and any other directories to which you will be writing), and instead use named docker volumes.

#### Hardcoding container names

In some places, you are hardcoding the container name, like this:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7.21
  container_name: dl-mysql
```

This will cause problems if you attempt to start multiple instances of this project or multiple instances of the mysql container. Don't statically set the container name.

#### Deprecated links syntax

Your configuration is using the deprecated `links` syntax:

```
links:
  - mysql
```

Don't do that. In modern docker, containers on the same network can simply refer to each other by name. In other words, if your compose configuration has:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7.21
  restart: unless-stopped
  working_dir: /application
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=dldl
    - MYSQL_USER=docker
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=docker
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
  volumes:
    - ./../:/application
  ports:
    - "8007:3306"
```

Other containers in your compose stack can simply use the hostname `mysql` to refer to this service.

Comment: Thank you very much @larsks for your explanation with a lot of details, actually one of my concern is about updating the containers without downtime, so it's why I said load balancing, I want to update the containers and when it's done just send the traffic to the new one.

Comment: If you truly want zero-downtime updates you're going to need to investigate [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/), which includes options for performing [rolling updates of your servers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/). Using legacy `docker-compose` I think there will always be a brief window where there are no backends running. You could hack around this by splitting things into three projects (1 frontend project and 2 backend projects), which would allow to update each backend project individually, but that gets increasingly complicated.

Comment: I was looking for https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/ but it's maybe overkill for my needs

Comment: But I still don't know how to isolate 2 environments with the same docker-compose file in the same server :(

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run same compose file on a host without changing the port mappings because that will cause port conflict. I'd recommend creating a base compose file and using [extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to override port mappings for different environments.

Comment: Thank you @mukesh, interesting thing, I will try it later. I added a comment to larsks response, and it's what I'm trying to do